# Create CSV using dataset in Scala

Tags: scala, csv, databricks

I have created the CSV file from the dataset in the scala. It is creating the CSV file however it is of 0 bytes.

while reading through dbutils.fs.head(csv_path) its giving error

"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot head a directory: csv_path"

````
```result_dataset.coalesce(1)
   .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
   .option("charset", "UTF-8")
   .option("header", "true")
   .option("sep",",")
   .save(csv_path)```
````

Can anyone help me with this? I think CSV is getting corrupted while creating the file.
Any solution for this?

Comment: Your error says it all. `csv_path` isn't the file with the data in it, it is a parent directory where Spark will save the CSV file. Without `coalesce(1)`, the Dataframe would have written many csv files under `csv_path` - as it would expect each Spark executor to write their partitions to their own `part-0001...csv` file in that folder.

Comment: Note with coal race, it'll still be a directory, containing one CSV file

Comment: What is "coal race" ? as I am expecting only one CSV file. How can I achieve that? I am new to scala. Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Databricks in about 1 year, but as I recall you can save a data frame to a CSV like this.

Write the contents of dataframe in CSV format:

```
df.write.csv("/data/home/csv")
```

Write the whole dataframe into a single CSV file:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.csv("/data/home/sample.csv")
```

Just for completeness, if you want to read a CSV into a data frame, you can do it like this.

```
# path to file
path = 'file:/databricks/driver/us.csv'

# load data using sqlContext
df = sqlContext.read.format("csv")\
    .option("header","true")\
    .option("inferSchema","true")\
    .load(path)

# displat table format
display(df)
```